# Why isn't python printing statement above infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

The output of this code is just `bb`. I want to know why `cc` is not printed, meaning that the third line is not executed which is `print("cc")`.
This is the link - https://ideone.com/M7LyS3

```
print("bb")
s2=input()
print("cc")
while 0>-50:
    pass
print("qq")
```

Input = 5

Comment: Your post needs definitely more focus and FYI I cannot reproduce what you said.

Comment: This is python code. and just first print statement is executed. print("cc") is not

Comment: It's waiting for you to input something at line 2

Comment: Probably you aren't providing the input expected at line 2. I tried your code on the console and "cc" is printed, after providing an input

Comment: Have you tried removing the lines after print("cc") - if that has cc being output, the issue is not that the third line is not executed.

Comment: What string did you enter for `s2`?  If you didn't enter one, then it's waiting for you to do so before proceeding to the next statement and printing `"cc"`.

Comment: https://ideone.com/M7LyS3
This is the link of code i compiled

Comment: i have entered a random string for s2

Comment: Did you hit the enter key after typing the string?  Python won't see it until you terminate the line with the enter key.

Comment: yes i obviously hit the enter key

Comment: It's possibly a buffering issue, although if the output is going to a terminal then it should be line buffered so you should be seeing `cc` after entering your input string.  You could test it by adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after `print("cc")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print` does not flush by default. Here, your first print in queued, and then flushed when you call `input()`. The second print is queued, but is never flushed.

If you add the optional `flush` argument, you'll get the behavior you expect:

```py
print("bb", flush = True)
s2=input()
print("cc"", flush = True)
while 0>-50:
    pass
print("qq"", flush = True) # Will never happen because of the infinite loop, though
```

Answer (score 3):

Try copying your code in this online compiler here:
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler

It works as you expected.

The reason it's not printing `cc` on your machine might be because of some issues or race condition of the buffer that prints output. The program gets busy in that infinite loop and is holding the buffer to be written to the terminal/console.

Comment: That's rubbish, there's no race condition involved. This is standard output caching, unless you flush your output, the output buffer will not be shown until your program properly ends. When the program is terminated, you'd expect the stdout output will still appear. Somehow this isn't the case for IDEONE, perhaps it captures the output right until before it kills the stalled program.

Answer (score 2):

The code is running fine:

```
print("bb")
s2=input()
print("cc")
while 0>-50:
    pass
print("qq")
```

Output:

```
bb
my_input
cc
```